# The nonword characters delimiter "\W" counts "comma+space" as a character

Tags: java, delimiter

Given a string, matching the regular expression `[A-Za-z !,?._'@]+`, I want to split the string into tokens. The token is one or more consecutive English alphabetic letters. Then, I want to print the number of tokens. This is my code:

```
public class mySolution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String [] parts = new String[1159];
    parts = s.split("\\W");
    System.out.println(parts.length);
    for(int i = 0; i< parts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(parts[i]);
    }
    scan.close();
}
}
```

This is the input I tried :

```
He is a very very good boy, isn't he?
```

And this is the output I receive:

```
11
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

As you see, everything's fine but the number of tokens turned out to be 11, while it should be 10! I believe the nonword characters delimiter `"\W"` is counting "comma+space" as a character! Am I right?

Comment: You would actually get `12` parts (`["He", "is", "a", "very", "very", "good", "boy", "", "isn", "t", "he", ""]`), but `String.split()` discards empty strings at the end. And yes your asumption is correct

Comment: You should split using `s.split("\\W+");` then space and comma are treated as one separator.

Comment: but there is not empty string after "he" at the end.